# Catkin_make is unable to find package present in source folder

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to work on [Hector SLAM](https://github.com/NickL77/RPLidar_Hector_SLAM) as per the instructions at the link.

I have ROS Kinetic installed in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I was able to clone the repository using the following code

```
cd catkin_workspace/src
git clone https://github.com/NickL77/RPLidar_Hector_SLAM
```

Once the repository is cloned I tried to compile the package

```
cd catkin_workspace
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps Rplidar_Hector_SLAM
```

The result is

```
 Base path: /home/rnd415/catkin_workspace
 Source space: /home/rnd415/catkin_workspace/src
 Build space: /home/rnd415/catkin_workspace/build
 Devel space: /home/rnd415/catkin_workspace/devel
 Install space: /home/rnd415/catkin_workspace/install
 Packages "RPLidar_Hector_SLAM" not found in the workspace
```

I don't know why ros is unable to find the package
I tried to sourcing the environment using

```
source /catkin_workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

but it does not change the error. How to resolve this error ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328453/catkin_make-is-unable-to-find-package-present-in-source-folder/) by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of the directory `!=` of the package(s).

The repository is called `RPLidar_Hector_SLAM`, so `git` will `clone` it into a directory `RPLidar_Hector_SLAM`.

However, the repository contains two sub directories (which happen to contain packages with the same name):

- hector_slam
- rplidar_ros

*those* are the packages.

`--only-pkg-with-deps` only accepts names of packages, not of directories.

Note btw that both `hector_slam` as well as `rplidar_ros` are standalone packages that are normally hosted somewhere else. The `NickL77/RPLidar_Hector_SLAM` repository places them together, but does not track upstream. And it contains a snapshot of both packages of already 2.5 years old.

You may want to make sure you are not missing important bug fixes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on 2019-07-13**:
I was able to clone the repositories from the master links.

for Hector SLAM : https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam
for RPlIdar : https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros